# How to launch ScenicView as a Java Agent in an IntelliJ Project?

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, javafx-8

I have added ScenicView to my JavaFX application in IntelliJ using the following VM Argument`-javaagent:/full/path/to/ScenicView.jar` as suggested in http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/help/.

However, when I launch the application, I get an `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute` exception along with a few others and as a result ScenicView is never able to discover my application.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw in the documentation that ScenicView requires `tools.jar` from the JDK to be available in the classpath.

It turns out that IntelliJ only loads JRE libraries to classpath even if you point out to a full JDK as the SDK. I have added `tools.jar` from the JDK to the classpath at `Module Settings -> SDKs -> Classpath`.

After this small fix, everything works as expected.